# Modal PopUp won't open again if it is closed without canceling row editing in a gridview placed within the modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview, modalpopupextender

I have a gridview with in place editing. This gridview is placed within a modal pop extender.
Everything works fine, but if I edit a row and **enter data that doesn't meet the validations rules** (RegularExpressionValidator) and **then close the modal popup**, the modal won't open again.

I have tried different things, like [using jquery to find the Cancel](https://taditdash.wordpress.com/tag/rowcancelingedit/) link and fire its click event, but nothing seems to work. 
In the end I also tried to fire the cancel edit within the javascript function the closes the modal, but the problem still remains.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

JS

```
<script src="script/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function CerrarPopup(strMpeCliente) {

            // Find the Generated Cancel Button for the Row in Edit Mode.
            var cancelButton = $('#<%= GridView2.ClientID %>')
                               .find('a')
                               .filter(function() { return $(this).text() === "Cancelar" });

            // If Cancel Button is found, then show message and click the Cancel Button.
            if (cancelButton != null && cancelButton.length > 0) {
                buttonClick(cancelButton[0]);

            }
            var modalPopupBehavior = $find(strMpeCliente);
            modalPopupBehavior.hide();

        }
        function buttonClick(button) {
            button.click();
        }    
    </script>
```

ASP

```
<cc1:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
</cc1:ToolkitScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upnlPagos" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#3AC0F2" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White"
            runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" ItemStyle-Width="30" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="btnViewDetails" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>'
                            OnClick="View" runat="server" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:LinkButton Text="" ID="lnkFake" runat="server" />
        <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpe" runat="server" PopupControlID="pnlPopup" TargetControlID="lnkFake"
            CancelControlID="btnClose" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" BehaviorID="mpeDetalles">
        </cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlPopup" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" Style="display: none">
            <div class="header">
                Details <a class="dvCerrar" href="javascript:;" onclick="CerrarPopup('mpeDetalles');"
                    title="Cerrar">&nbsp;&nbsp;X&nbsp;&nbsp; </a>
            </div>
            <div class="body">
                <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#3AC0F2" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White"
                    runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowEditing="gvPrueba_RowEditing"
                    OnRowUpdating="gvPrueba_RowUpdating" OnRowCancelingEdit="gvPrueba_RowCancelingEdit">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" ItemStyle-Width="30" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblCorreo" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Email")%>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtCorreo" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Email")%>' MaxLength="70"
                                    Width="180px"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revtxtCorreo" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtCorreo"
                                    ErrorMessage="" ValidationExpression="^\s*([\w\.\-]+)@([\w\-]+)((\.(\w){2,3})+)\s*$"
                                    Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red" ToolTip="Formato de correo incorrecto">*</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:CommandField HeaderText="Editar" ButtonType="Link" ShowEditButton="true" ShowCancelButton="true"
                            CancelText="Cancelar" EditText="Editar" UpdateText="Guardar"></asp:CommandField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
            </div>
            <div class="footer" align="right">
                <asp:Button ID="btnClose" runat="server" Text="Close" CssClass="button" 
                    onclick="btnClose_Click" />
            </div>
        </asp:Panel>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

CS

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!this.IsPostBack)
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[5] { new DataColumn("Id", typeof(int)),
                        new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)),
                        new DataColumn("Country",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("City",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("Phone",typeof(int))});
                dt.Rows.Add(1, "John Hammond", "United States", "Lasvagas", 1234567899);
                dt.Rows.Add(2, "Mudassar Khan", "India", "Mumbai", 1234567899);
                dt.Rows.Add(3, "Suzanne Mathews", "France", "Paris", 1234567899);
                dt.Rows.Add(4, "Robert Schidner", "Russia", "Mascow", 1234567899);
                GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                GridView1.DataBind();
                ViewState["Table"] = dt;




                //DETALLE

                DataTable dtDetalle = new DataTable();
                dtDetalle.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] { new DataColumn("Id", typeof(int)),
                        new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)),
                        new DataColumn("Email",typeof(string))});          

                dtDetalle.Rows.Add(1, "John Hammond", "jj@siempresof.tom");
                dtDetalle.Rows.Add(2, "Mudassar Khan", "aj@siempresof.tom");
                dtDetalle.Rows.Add(3, "Suzanne Mathews", "eej@siempresof.tom");
                dtDetalle.Rows.Add(4, "Robert Schidner", "tttj@siempresof.tom");
                ViewState["tbDetalle"] = dtDetalle;
            }
        }
        protected void gvPrueba_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
        {
            GridView2.EditIndex = -1;
            FillGrid();


        }
        protected void gvPrueba_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
        {
            GridView2.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
            FillGrid();

        }
        protected void gvPrueba_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {   
            GridView2.EditIndex = -1;
        }
        protected void View(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            FillGrid();
        }
        private void FillGrid()
        {
            DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["tbDetalle"];            
            GridView2.DataSource = dt;
            GridView2.DataBind();
            mpe.Show();
        }    

        protected void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GridView2.EditIndex = -1;
            mpe.Hide();
        }
```

As always any help will be GREATLY appreciated

Thanks in advance.

P.S. Here's a link with the complete [source code](https://www.mediafire.com/?5pl4i1rmbw6e22h) of my simplified version.

Answer (score 0):

Hiding or Showing the modal popup extender still holds the modal popup in memory (in the page), so the validation still blocks postbacks (what happens when you try to save or cancel normally) unless you close it through Javascript (I think).

So I think the reason why the popup doesn't open up anymore is because in the background the validation is still failing on the modal, and thus disallowing to show its self again.

Have you tried using `CausesValidation=false` on the cancel button?

Best regards.